# How can i show accented characters with hotstrings?

Tags: utf-8, autohotkey

How can i display the chraracters with accent, hotstrings autohotkey. 
Is not displaying the correct text...
For example, look the code:

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoTrayIcon
#NoEnv

:*O:compraplatina::Olá, como vai? +{Enter} VocÊ quer troféus? Não será feito dessa forma, razoável
```

The result when i type "compraplatina":
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh1Tr.png)

Comment: Interesting. It came out just fine for me (in Notepad). What are you typing it into? What font is being used?

Comment: Save the script again as UTF-8 *with* BOM, see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#nonascii